# Instruction index: 0 Reason: A seeds constraint was violated. Getting this while testing in playground for the UpdateFund ctx

Tags: anchor, solana-program, testing, seed

[image]

```
#[program]
pub mod fund {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_user(
        ctx:Context<InitializeUser>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("User Initialized");
        let user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;
        user_profile.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key();
        user_profile.fund_count = 0;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn create_fund(
        ctx:Context<CreateFund>,
        fund_name: String,
        fund_description: String,
        target_amount: u64,
    ) -> Result<()>{
        msg!("Fund Account Created");
        msg!("Fund Name: {}", fund_name);
        msg!("Fund Description: {}", fund_description);
        msg!("Target Amount: {}", target_amount);

        // Getting State
        let fund_account = &mut ctx.accounts.fund_account;
        let user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;

        // Filling the account with values we get
        fund_account.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key();
        fund_account.fund_name = fund_name;
        fund_account.fund_description = fund_description;
        fund_account.target_amount = target_amount;

        // Incrementing total fund accounts
        user_profile.fund_count = user_profile.fund_count.checked_add(1).unwrap();
        
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_fund(
        ctx:Context<UpdateFund>,
        // fund_name: String,
        fund_description: String,
        target_amount: u64,
    )-> Result<()> {
        msg!("Fund Account Updated");
        // msg!("Fund Name: {}", fund_name);
        msg!("Fund Description: {}", fund_description);
        msg!("Target Amount: {}", target_amount);

        
        let _user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;
        let fund_account = &mut ctx.accounts.fund_account;
        
        fund_account.fund_description =  fund_description;
        fund_account.target_amount = target_amount;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn closefund(
        ctx:Context<CloseFund>,
    ) -> Result<()>{
        let user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;

        user_profile.fund_count = user_profile.fund_count.checked_sub(1).unwrap();

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]

pub struct InitializeUser<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = ["fund".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<UserProfile>(),
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info,UserProfile>>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]
pub struct CreateFund<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["fund".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info,UserProfile>>,

    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = ["create".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref(),&[user_profile.fund_count as u8].as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<FundAccountState>()
    )]
    pub fund_account: Box<Account<'info,FundAccountState>>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority:Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}
    
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]    
pub struct UpdateFund<'info>{
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["fund".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info,UserProfile>>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["create".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref(), &user_profile.fund_count.to_le_bytes()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
        realloc = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<FundAccountState>(),
        realloc::payer = authority,
        realloc::zero = true
        
    )]
    pub fund_account: Box<Account<'info,FundAccountState>>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority:Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(fund_count:u8)]
pub struct CloseFund<'info>{
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["fund".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info,UserProfile>>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        close = authority,
        seeds = ["create".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref(),&[fund_count as u8].as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
    )]
    pub fund_account: Box<Account<'info,FundAccountState>>,

     #[account(mut)]
    pub authority:Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}


#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct UserProfile {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub fund_count: u8,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct FundAccountState {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub fund_name: String,
    pub fund_description: String,
    pub target_amount: u64,
}
```

Comment: Were you able to test the `createFund` instruction successfully? It looks like the `fund_account` in your program requires 3 seeds, and the Test UI on solpg only allows two seeds. You may have to try testing the instruction in the `anchor.test.ts` file and deriving the PDA for the `fund_account` using `findProgramAddress`

Comment: but I was able to test `CreateFund` ix in solpg successfully. I will try deriving with findProgramAddress.

Comment: @john you can add more than two seeds in Test UI

Comment: Oops, sorry that's my bad. Just realized you can click the  (+) button to add seeds multiple times. Thanks for building Solpg!

Comment: @john thank you, good to know this is confusing people as there is an open PR to make seeds more intuitive https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/pull/113

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because in the `create_fund` instruction, you increase the `fund_count` by 1 with this line:

```
// Incrementing total fund accounts
user_profile.fund_count = user_profile.fund_count.checked_add(1).unwrap();
```

but `update_fund` instruction generates the `fund_account` seeds from the same seeds

```
seeds = [
    "create".as_bytes(),
    authority.key().as_ref(),
    &user_profile.fund_count.to_le_bytes()
],
```

Notice how you've increased `user_profile.fund_count` but the instruction only generates the seeds from the current `user_profile.fund_count`. This means that if the user's `fund_count` is 1 then after calling the `create_fund` instruction `fund_count` will be set to 2. And after you call the `update_fund` instruction the seeds `&user_profile.fund_count.to_le_bytes()` will be `[2]` instead of `[1]`, hence the "A seed constraint was violated" error.

There are many ways you can fix this, the easiest one is to pass `fund_count` as an instruction argument by

1. Updating the instruction arguments

```
pub fn update_fund(
    ctx: Context<UpdateFund>,
    fund_count: u8,
    fund_description: String,
    target_amount: u64,
)
```

2. Adding instruction macro

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(fund_count: u8)]
pub struct UpdateFund<'info> {...}
```

3. Update `fund_account` seeds

```
#[account(
    seeds = [
        "create".as_bytes(),
        authority.key().as_ref(),
        &[fund_count]
    ],
    // ...
)]
pub fund_account: Box<Account<'info, FundAccountState>>,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ser.The test feature in solpg is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction()]    
pub struct UpdateFund<'info>{
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["fund".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info,UserProfile>>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["create".as_bytes(),authority.key().as_ref(), &[user_profile.fund_count as u8].as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
        realloc = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<FundAccountState>(),
        realloc::payer = authority,
        realloc::zero = true
        
    )]
    pub fund_account: Box<Account<'info,FundAccountState>>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority:Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
}
```